# Autofixture ObjectCreationException - circular reference: RuntimeParameterInfo or Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net, autofixture

I've been trying to model some simple immutable objects, in which I have two constructor overloads: one which accepts an argument for each of the readonly properties, and one which accepts an instance of itself for cloning (for ease of use when most property values will be the same as another instance's).

```cs
public class Parent {
    public Parent(Child child, Pet pet) {
        Child = child;
        Pet = pet;
    }

    public Parent(Parent template) {
        Child = template.Child;
        Pet = template.Pet;
    }

    public Child Child { get; private set; }
    public Pet Pet { get; private set; }
}
```

This test passes, as I would expect:

```cs
[Theory]
[AutoData]
public void Properties_Equal_Constructor_Arguments(Child expectedChild, Pet expectedPet)
{
    // act
    var sut = new Parent(expectedChild, expectedPet);

    // assert
    sut.Child.Should().Be(expectedChild);
    sut.Pet.Should().Be(expectedPet);
}
```

But this test throws a `Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException`, unable to create an instance of type `System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo` (using AutoData parameter), or type `Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest` (without using AutoData) **(?!?)**

```cs
[Theory]
[AutoData]
public void Properties_Equal_Properties_Of_Template_Constructor_Argument(Parent template)
{
    // arrange
    //var fixture = new Fixture();            // yields same error but for type
    //var template = fixture.Create<Parent>();// Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
    var expectedChild = template.Child;
    var expectedPet = template.Pet;

    // act
    var sut = new Parent(template);

    // assert
    sut.Child.Should().Be(expectedChild);
    sut.Pet.Should().Be(expectedPet);
}
```

First of all, I don't spot any circular reference in my classes, like you usually see in questions about this where the child object has a property reference to its parent (like happens with database entity modeling sometimes). Second, when I have received this error in the past, it was referring to a circular reference on a type plainly used in my class, unlike in this case.

**Why is this happening?**

For completeness, here are the other relevant classes and the full error message received:

```cs
public class Child {
    public Child(string value) {
        Value = value;
    }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
}

public class Pet {
    public Pet(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException An exception was thrown while getting
>   data for theory
>   AutoFixtureTests.CircularReferenceTests.Properties_Equal_Properties_Of_Template_Constructor_Argument:
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException: AutoFixture was unable to
>   create an instance of type System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo
>   because the traversed object graph contains a circular reference.
>   Information about the circular path follows below. This is the correct
>   behavior when a Fixture is equipped with a ThrowingRecursionBehavior,
>   which is the default. This ensures that you are being made aware of
>   circular references in your code. Your first reaction should be to
>   redesign your API in order to get rid of all circular references.
>   However, if this is not possible (most likely because parts or all of
>   the API is delivered by a third party), you can replace this default
>   behavior with a different behavior: on the Fixture instance, remove
>   the ThrowingRecursionBehavior from Fixture.Behaviors, and instead add
>   an instance of OmitOnRecursionBehavior.   Path:
>         AutoFixtureTests.Parent template -->        AutoFixtureTests.Parent --> 
>         AutoFixtureTests.Parent template --> 
>         Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
>
> at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.ThrowingRecursionHandler.HandleRecursiveRequest(Object
>   request, IEnumerable`1 recordedRequests)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TracingBuilder.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.MethodInvoker.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TracingBuilder.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TracingBuilder.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TracingBuilder.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object
>   request, ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request,
>   ISpecimenContext context)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Xunit.AutoDataAttribute.GetData(MethodInfo
>   methodUnderTest, Type[] parameterTypes)    at
>   Xunit.Extensions.TheoryAttribute.d_*7.MoveNext()    at
>   Xunit.Extensions.TheoryAttribute.EnumerateTestCommands(IMethodInfo
>   method)    at
>   Xunit.Extensions.TheoryAttribute.<>c*_DisplayClass5.b__1()
>   at
>   Xunit.Extensions.TheoryAttribute.LambdaTestCommand.Execute(Object testClass)

**and when not using AutoDataAttribute:**

> Ploeh.AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException AutoFixture was unable to
>   create an instance of type Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
>   because the traversed object graph contains a circular reference.
>   Information about the circular path follows below. This is the correct
>   behavior when a Fixture is equipped with a ThrowingRecursionBehavior,
>   which is the default. This ensures that you are being made aware of
>   circular references in your code. Your first reaction should be to
>   redesign your API in order to get rid of all circular references.
>   However, if this is not possible (most likely because parts or all of
>   the API is delivered by a third party), you can replace this default
>   behavior with a different behavior: on the Fixture instance, remove
>   the ThrowingRecursionBehavior from Fixture.Behaviors, and instead add
>   an instance of OmitOnRecursionBehavior.   Path:
>         AutoFixtureTests.Parent template -->        AutoFixtureTests.Parent --> 
>         AutoFixtureTests.Parent    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.ThrowingRecursionHandler.HandleRecursiveRequest(Object request, IEnumerable`1 recordedRequests)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TracingBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TracingBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.MethodInvoker.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TracingBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.Postprocessor`1.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.CompositeSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TracingBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.TerminatingWithPathSpecimenBuilder.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.RecursionGuard.Create(Object request, ISpecimenContext context)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.Create(ISpecimenContext context, T seed)
>   at Ploeh.AutoFixture.SpecimenFactory.Create(ISpecimenContext context) 
>   at
>   AutoFixtureTests.CircularReferenceTests.Properties_Equal_Properties_Of_Template_Constructor_Argument()
>   in AutoFixtureTests.cs: line 28

Comment: The circular reference is right here: `public Parent(Parent template)`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann True! Examples I've seen so far had the `Child` property referencing its own `Parent` in its property. I thought that, since AF is only being asked to create one `Parent` instance (I'm creating the other) that it would be ok. But just in creating the first one, it has to create another for the constructor, again and again. Makes perfect sense. I'm going to see if this goes away if I use the `GreedyConstructorQuery` so it picks the other constructor (with two arguments). In this case is AF pointing out a 'smell'? As always, many thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to avoid a circular reference as a result of Entity Framework and virtual members, here is a customization to ignore them when generating mock data.

```
public class IgnoreVirtualMembers : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public Type ReflectedType { get; }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (pi != null) //// is a property
        {
            if (this.ReflectedType == null || //// is hosted anywhere
                this.ReflectedType == pi.ReflectedType) //// is hosted in defined type
            {
                if (pi.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual)
                {
                    return new OmitSpecimen();
                }
            }
        }

        return new NoSpecimen();
    }
}

public class IgnoreVirtualMembersCustomisation : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new IgnoreVirtualMembers());
    }
}
```

With the usage :

```
new Fixture().Customize(new IgnoreVirtualMembersCustomisation());
```

Comment: This is a life saver for the circular reference error that autofixture complains of when using entity framework. Thank you. By the way, do you have a similar solution for when AutoMoqData is being used instead of fixture?

Comment: Sorry no, never used it

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I got it working using your solution.